# Shouldn't it be $d\sin\theta=\frac{\lambda}{2}$ here instead of $d\sin\theta=\lambda$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, interference, double-slit-experiment, wavelength

**Question:**

The width of a slit is $4\times 10^{-4}cm$. The wavelength of the light used is $6000 A^{\circ}$. What is the angular distance between the two minima of first order on both sides of the central maximum?

**My attempt:**

We know,

Path difference, $\Delta x=d\sin\theta$, where $d$ is the width of the slit, and $\theta$ is the angular distance of the bright or dark fringe from the central maximum. Now,

$$\Delta x=d\sin\theta$$

$$(2n+1)\frac{\lambda}{2}=d\sin\theta$$

$$[\text{I used $(2n+1)\frac{\lambda}{2}$ as it is a dark fringe or minimum. Let's input n=0 for the first minimum.}]$$

$$d\sin\theta=\frac{\lambda}{2}$$

$$\sin\theta=\frac{\lambda}{2d}$$

$$\sin\theta=\frac{6000\times 10^{-10}}{2\times 4\times 10^{-6}}$$

$$\theta=4.301^{\circ}$$

Now, the required angular distance $=2\theta=2\times 4.301^{\circ}=8.602^{\circ}\text{(Ans.)}$

**My book's attempt:**

$$n\lambda=d\sin\theta$$

$$\sin\theta=\frac{n\lambda}{d}$$

$$\sin\theta=\frac{1\times 6000\times 10^{-10}}{4\times 10^{-6}}$$

$$\theta=8.6269^{\circ}$$

Now, the required angular distance $=2\theta=2\times 8.6269^{\circ}=17.25^{\circ}\text{(Ans.)}$

**My question:**

1. Why did my book use $n\lambda=d\sin\theta$ instead of $(2n+1)\frac{\lambda}{2}=d\sin\theta$ when we are working with minima?

Comment: I believe this question involves a diffraction pattern, and not an interference pattern.

Comment: In a single slit diffraction experiment, the dark fringes are given by $n\lambda=d\sin\theta$ for $n\ne 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I believe the law is $2d \sin \theta = \lambda$ when you consider this:

[image: Bragg 1]

And $d \sin \theta = \lambda$ when you consider this:

[image: Bragg 2]

but I'm not 100% sure so check anyway

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to SE. If you aren't sure, please don't post this as an answer. Remember that this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.

Comment: The question is not about x-ray diffraction pattern.